# Laravel with moneris

Tags: laravel-5.1

Can anyone advice me how can I add Moneris payment metnod with laravel 5.1 ?

I have a merchant account. But I am not sure if laravel supports monaris or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel by itself doesn't support Moneris (nor any payment processor). However, you can integrate Moneris (and the Moneris API) into your Laravel application by following the directives listed on their [developer portal](https://developer.moneris.com/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/API).

Compared to modern payment solutions, such as Stripe or Braintree, Moneris' API can be pretty tedious to use. If you are only using basic purchase, verify, preauth, capture, and refund operations, I suggest you to check out [Keith Silgard's library](https://github.com/ironkeith/moneris-eselectplus-api).

However, if you need to implement other operations, such as adding a card to the Vault, you will have to follow Moneris' examples and adapt them to fit into your Laravel Application. For (a very rough) example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use mpgClasses;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

    protected function addCardToMonerisVault(Request $request) {

    /**************************** Request Variables *******************************/

    $store_id=getenv('MONERIS_STORE_ID');
    $api_token=getenv('MONERIS_API_KEY');

    /************************* Transactional Variables ****************************/

    $type='res_add_cc';
    $cust_id= Auth::user()->id;
    $pan=preg_replace('/\D/', '', $request->input('number'));
    $expiry_date=$request->input('expiry_year') . $request->input('expiry_month');
    $crypt_type='1';
    $avs_street_number = '';
    $avs_street_name = '';
    $avs_zipcode = '';

    /*********************** Transactional Associative Array **********************/

    $txnArray=array('type'=>$type,
            'cust_id'=>$cust_id,
            'pan'=>$pan,
            'expdate'=>$expiry_date,
            'crypt_type'=>$crypt_type
        );

    /**************************** Transaction Object *****************************/

    $mpgTxn = new \mpgTransaction($txnArray);

    /****************************** Request Object *******************************/

    $mpgRequest = new \mpgRequest($mpgTxn);

    /***************************** HTTPS Post Object *****************************/

    $mpgHttpPost  =new \mpgHttpsPost($store_id,$api_token,$mpgRequest);

    /******************************* Response ************************************/


    $response = $mpgHttpPost->response;

    return $response;

    }
```

}